# How to grant write access to a folder in ASP.NET MVC site with IIS7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As the title says.

Can some give me instructions how to do this
as I cannot see how.
I am used to IIS5 & 6.

Also when I try to add write access to the folder
in explorer there is no Add option to add a user ie ASPNET account.

This is on Vista

Malcolm

Comment: Are you taking about a physical folder or some RESTful path that's used in Asp.net MVC?

Comment: Yes physical, I want to write to an XML file??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to grant access to the `IIS_USRS` group (for the AppPool) and the `IUSR` user (for anonymous access / static content).

Comment: @blo0p3r - Right you are sir

Answer (score 4):

IIS 6 and IIS 7 are using NETWORK SERVICE as account for access to the system resources. You need to give rights to this account

Comment: My question is how, in the IIS UI?

Comment: You need to switch to the content view and select required folder there. After in the right panel you can use edit permissions link.

Comment: This is not true for IIS7.5 / Windows 7

Comment: It is true for Win 7. Select required site and so on.

Comment: @Sly - Sorry, I meant NETWORK SERVICE is not true for Win7.