# ASP.NET MVC System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I am new in ASP.NET MVC and I have a problem. When I publish my web application on my [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) hosting account, and when I go to change file I get a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` exception:

```
Access to the string "path" is denied in this part of code

string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/currentImage.txt");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

I try to add `<identity impersonate="true"/>` in **Web.config** but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Has the website got write-permissions on the physical folder on disk that the Server.MapPath() is mapping to...?

Comment: The ~/Content folder has to have write permissions for the *application pool's identity*.  Impersonate will need permissions for the person running the app, which you don't want.

Comment: How to get it to this folder?

Comment: There are many question here that cover this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486011/how-to-grant-write-access-to-a-folder-in-asp-net-mvc-site-with-iis7, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062741/grant-asp-net-mvc-3-website-write-access-to-content-uploads-folder, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315026/write-to-a-file-on-iis. And this has some detailed steps with a screenshot  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/setting-folder-permissions. I don't know if AppHarbor allows this level of control.